# simple calculation using logs

Tags: algorithms, logarithms

Suppose we are comparing implementations of insertion sort and merge sort on the same
machine. For inputs of size $n\in\mathbb{N}$, insertion sort runs in $8n^2$ steps, while merge sort runs in $64n\log(n)$ steps. For which values of $n$ does insertion sort beat merge sort?

Comment: Note: n belongs to the natural numbers

Comment: It's equivalent to solving $n<8\log(n)$. Assuming the logarithm is 2-based, if $2\leq n\leq 32$, the inequality holds. The exact range can be approximated numerically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving $8n^2 \lt 64n\log(n)$ (equivalently, $n\lt 8\log(n)$) exactly requires use of Lambert's [W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert%27s_W_function). Solving it approximately is pretty easy.

At $n=1$, $8n^2\gt 64n\log(n)$; at $n=2$, $8n^2 \lt 64n\log(n)$; if $\log$ is base $2$, then they cross again at about $n=45$.